# What is the benefit of creating an Object in Java?

Tags: java, object

I would like to know what is benefit of creating an object in Java.  Because i can refer to methods , variables etc.  of  that class without creating an object for example.  `SecondClass second = null;  second.start();`

Comment: No you cannot, unless start is static (and you should call it as SecondClass.start() if it is a static).

Comment: You first need to understand the difference between instance and static methods. Then you will have your answer.

Comment: You'll have better luck googling for things like "object-oriented programming," and the point thereof. You asked a big question.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would highly recommend a beginner's book on Java (Or object oriented programming) or at the very least starting with the tutorials provided by Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is created so that you can encapsulate *local state.*  Each object instantiated from a class holds its own set of member variables.

Static methods do not require such encapsulation, but they don't hold local state, either.  You have to pass in any relevant state, and any variables you declare within the static method go out of scope when you leave the method body.

Any "advanced" OOP features such as inheritance and factory methods only have meaning within the context of an instantiated object.